# Jenkins Dockerfile declarative pipelines: getting the built image tag

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I'm trying to get the image tag generated with the help of the dockerfile agent in Jenkins declarative pipelines.

This Jenkinsfile is incomplete though, because I still need the deployment steps.

Normally, people would then want a step to push to Dockerhub. Although I don't even know how to do that, I want something different: **I want to re-tag the built image locally** to a name of my choice. This is because this is a hobby project, and my Jenkins and production servers are the same. The **problem is that I don't know how to get the dynamically generated image ID** for the `docker tag` command.

(Then what would come next is to swap out the old running image with the new one, but I could probably take care of that myself.)

Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            args '--network szeremi -e DB_HOST=mysql -e APP_ENV=testing'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Run tests') {
            steps {
                sh 'cd /var/www && php artisan migrate:fresh && vendor/bin/phpunit'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me use Jenkins declarative pipelines to re-tag my built-by-dockerfile image.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to add a variable to the docker image tag,

in this case, you have to get an environment variable from Jenkins and use it in your image label.

```
    pipeline {
  environment {
    registry = "docker_hub_account/repository_name"
    registryCredential = 'dockerhub'
  }
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Building image') {
      steps{
        script {
          docker.build registry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

pleae use this [URL](https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-building-docker-image-and-sending-to-registry-64b84ea45ee9) for more info

Comment: No. I don't want to use a pre-existing Docker image from the registry (`docker` agent), I want to build a new Docker image from the Dockerfile in my project (`dockerfile` agent). I know I can use variables, but the problem is that I don't know how to dynamically get the image tag of the newly built image.

Comment: OK, I will edit my answer

Comment: Still not OK. I want to make use of the `dockerfile` agent. You are using the `any` agent now.

Comment: I think you can't use the agent which you still need to add a tag to it from build number, The Idea from the agent that you have already up and running container connected to Jenkins as a node and it used to build your code ( for your case you need to run docker command so the user agent should have docker command on this agent )

Comment: @AhmedBadawy how to pass build argument to docker.build?

Answer (score 1):

`docker build` *does* output the image ID:

```
Successfully built 6fd2b9d56348
Successfully tagged foo:latest
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the [Docker Build Step plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-build-step-plugin) exposes it to the pipeline (it *does* write it to the log!). You may want to open an issue with that project.

That said, `docker tag` itself accepts `name:tag`:

```
$ docker help tag
Usage:  docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]
```

Since you (can) choose image name and first tag for `docker build`, try using those to identify the built image instead of its ID. If that doesn't work with the plugin, you may need a feature request after all.

As a workaround, you can always use `sh script: 'docker ...'` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need `additionalBuildArgs` to tag your image as `mytag`:

```java
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            additionalBuildArgs '-t mytag'
        }
    }
```